# Jquery text search and do something with that text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get something that looks through a div with an id of 'Holder' and searches for a string. Preferably this string would be case-insensitive. This string would be have an input connected (variable is 'Terms'). Once the code has found all the paragraphs that have the string, add a class to them called 'Found'. I do not have that much knowledge with Jquery (just the very basics) so if anyone could help me, that would be fantastic!

Code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<body>
    <p id="header">Searcher</p>
    <hr>
    <p id="form">
    <input autocomplete="off" id="Bar" name="Input" type="text"     placeholder="Search for word or phrase">
    <button type="button" id="sea" onClick="Search ()">Search</button>
    <br>
    </p>
    <div id="Holder">
        <p id="Note">This is a test paragraph uses to test.</p>
        <p id="Note">For jquery. I want to search for this paragraph using "for jquery".</p>
    </div>


    <script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please, provide us with a jsfiddle?

Comment: have you tried anything?post what you have  tried..

Comment: Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mz0ge2w8/

Comment: please also post the code here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code sample.  You should read the comments because I made a few changes to how you were doing things in order to improve code quality.  There is still more that could be done (like using a real form), but this should get you pointed in the right direction.  If my comments aren't clear, feel free to ask why I made the changes that I did and I'll try to provide a better explanation.

```
<html>
  <style>
    .match-found {
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
      <p id="header">Searcher</p>
      <hr>
      <p id="form">
        <!-- 
          You should use a real form and attach to the submit handler, but I
          feel the need to leave something as an exercise for the reader
        -->
        <input autocomplete="off" id="bar" name="input" type="text" placeholder="Search for word or phrase">
        <button type="button" class="search-text" data-search-target="#holder">Search</button>
      <br>
      </p>
      <div id="holder">
          <p id="note">This is a test paragraph uses to test.</p>
          <p id="note">For jquery. I want to search for this paragraph using "for jquery".</p>
      </div>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        function search(searchTarget, term) {
          // lowercase terms because uppercase should be reserved for constructors
          // also made it singular because we're looking for an exact match, not
          // a list several separate terms.
          // (if I understand your problem description correctly)
          term = term.toLowerCase();

          // If you're searching for simple terms, regex would be better,
          // but since I'm not sure how you'll actually be using this, 
          // lowercasing the string and searching for a containing string will
          // provide more consistent results because we won't have to worry about
          // escaping special characters and the like.
          $(searchTarget).find('p').each(function() {
            var searchText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if (searchText.indexOf(term) !== -1) $(this).addClass('match-found');
            // match-found is more descriptive that 'found'.  
            // Also avoiding caps again because capitilization has specific meaning
          });
        }

        // A better way to attach event listeners
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.search-text').click(function() {
            var searchTarget = $(this).attr('data-search-target');
            var searchText = $('#bar').val();
            search(searchTarget, searchText);
          });
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sea").on("click", function() {
  $("#Holder > p:contains('" + $("#Bar").val() + "')").addClass("found");
});
```

The above code attaches a click event to the search button `#sea`. Using the `:contains()` selector it searches all `<p>` tags which are direct children of `#Holder` for the value of `#Bar` and adds the class "found".

https://jsfiddle.net/mz0ge2w8/1/